# Google Dataflow job failed with "insufficient data uploaded" error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to create a dataflow job that processes a few thousand files, and for each file, write to a different destination in GCS.

I have to do a lot of TextIO as source and write to destination as separate flow. A sample code snippet looks like this:

```html
List<PCollection<String>> pcs = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
        pcs.add(p.apply(TextIO.Read.from("gs://wushilin-asia/some-folder/input-" + i + "/*")));
}

for(int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
        pcs.get(i).apply(TextIO.Write.to("gs://wushilin-asia/some-folder/output-" + i + "/"));
}
p.run();
```

This fails silently (seems hanging forever) with error "insufficient data uploaded" in the backend.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: It turned out to be that the dataflow structure is too complicated and dataflow job metadata storage can't handle it. Reducing to less components solved this issu.e

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be that the dataflow structure is too complicated and dataflow job metadata storage can't handle it. Reducing to less components solved this issue